# Receiving error while updating OwnerId of the custom object from the experience site

Tags: experience-cloud, insufficient-privileges

I am trying to update the OwnerId field of a custom object from the Experience-Site, but I am receiving an error of insufficient access.

error :

`System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a3fVZ000000074jYAA; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []`

I checked the Permission of that Community-User. User has a Permission Set, which has access to read and edit the OwnerId-Field of that Custom-Object. I can update other fields of that object, but just receive errors while updating OwnerId.

Comment: There could be other reasons for this, such as not being able to see the new owner, the new owner not having the correct permissions to own the record (e.g. missing Read access on the object), or the current user not owning the record (ownership is more powerful than just "Edit" permission). You'll need to check your sharing settings and the new owner's profile and permission sets.